# Spi Transmit function which i wrote without HAL implementation is giving me some issue

Tags: stm32, spi

`void SPI_TransmitData(uint8_t data)`
`{`
`// Wait for TXE flag to be set`
`while (!(SPI2->SR & SPI_SR_TXE));`

```
// Write the data to the SPI data register
SPI2->DR = data;

// Wait for the transmission to complete
while (SPI2->SR & SPI_SR_BSY);
```

}

i am trying do my own SPI transmit function  where i am stuct in this function it self and i am not going to the next line after reading the function`your text`

Comment: The code you have shown is completely correct.  Your mistake is somewhere else, but there aren't enough details to say where.